# Python - Merging 2 lists of tuples by checking their values

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, tuples

I have lists like this:

```
a = [('JoN', 12668, 0.0036), ('JeSsIcA', 1268, 0.0536), ('JoN', 1668, 0.00305), ('King', 16810, 0.005)]
b = [('JoN', 12668, 0.0036), ('JON', 16680, 0.00305), ('MeSSi', 115, 0.369)]
```

I want the resultant list to be like:

```
result = [(('JoN', 12668, 0.0036), ('JoN', 12668, 0.0036)), (('JoN', 1668, 0.00305), ('JON', 16680, 0.00305)), (('King', 16810, 0.005), None), (None, ('MeSSi', 115, 0.369))]
```

I have tried nested loops, sets, map, zip but failed to achieve this output. kindly help me out.

Comment: What determines if they should be merged? As far as I can tell, the 1st and 3rd element of the tuples must match?

Comment: Why `(('JeSsIcA', 1268, 0.0536), None)` is not in the output?

Comment: Note that the 3rd component of the tuple is a float, and performing equality tests on floats is probably not going to work out like you expect it to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Convert `a` and `b` to dictionaries first using the first(use `str.lower()` in it) and third item as key and then later on loop on the union of the keys in a list comprehension to get the desired output:

```
>>> from pprint import pprint
>>> dct_a = {(x[0].lower(), x[2]): x for x in a}
>>> dct_b = {(x[0].lower(), x[2]): x for x in b}
>>> out = [(dct_a.get(k), dct_b.get(k)) for k in set(dct_a).union(dct_b)]
>>> pprint(out)
[(('JoN', 12668, 0.0036), ('JoN', 12668, 0.0036)),
 (('JoN', 1668, 0.00305), ('JON', 16680, 0.00305)),
 (('King', 16810, 0.005), None),
 (('JeSsIcA', 1268, 0.0536), None),
 (None, ('MeSSi', 115, 0.369))]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from string import lower
from itertools import groupby
from operator import itemgetter

def compose(f, g):
    def h(*args, **kwargs):
        return f(*g(*args, **kwargs))
    return h

def lower_first(*args):
    return (lower(args[0]),) + args[1:]

sorting_key = compose(lower_first, itemgetter(0, 2, 1))

grouping_key = compose(lower_first, itemgetter(0, 2))

output = [tuple(v) for k,v in groupby(sorted(a+b, key=sorting_key), 
                                      key=grouping_key)]
```

gives `output` as

```
[(('JeSsIcA', 1268, 0.0536),),
 (('JoN', 1668, 0.00305), ('JON', 16680, 0.00305)),
 (('JoN', 12668, 0.0036), ('JoN', 12668, 0.0036)),
 (('King', 16810, 0.005),),
 (('MeSSi', 115, 0.369),)]
```

Then adding the `None` values is easy:

```
final_output = [ elem if len(elem) >= 2 
    else ((None,)+ elem) if elem[0] not in a else elem + (None,) 
    for elem in output
]
```

which gives:

```
[(('JeSsIcA', 1268, 0.0536), None),
 (('JoN', 1668, 0.00305), ('JON', 16680, 0.00305)),
 (('JoN', 12668, 0.0036), ('JoN', 12668, 0.0036)),
 (('King', 16810, 0.005), None),
 (None, ('MeSSi', 115, 0.369))]
```

But you need to be careful, because stating a problem like this with lists often glosses over problems of relational joins that would be taken care of by a system with proper indexing, like a [`pandas.DataFrame`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/generated/pandas.DataFrame.html) which seems more likely to be the kind of data structure you want, due to its [native `join` and `merge` capabilities.](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.13.1/merging.html)

Comment: I don't understand why you're using `itemgetter` here-- every time you call `sorting_key` or `grouping_key` you're constructing multiple `itemgetter` instances only to do what `x[0]` would have done immediately.

Comment: Sorry, I meant to clean it up into helpfer functions. My experience is that throwing around `lambda`s as keys to things like `sorted` leads to bad code, so I tend to separate things pretty pedantically into different little functions that perform this different actions. I will edit to demonstrate what I mean -- but I also acknowledge that it's not something everyone likes.

Comment: I made the edits. I think of this as "lambda-free" style, which is kind of like striving for "point-free" style in Haskell. It's sometimes better to just have a short readable lambda, but usually not. And I also find that these little annoying conditions that go into the sorting or grouping often get changed or tweaked in tiny ways, and then it's almost like hard-coding them to put them in a lambda, and item-getting or attr-getting inside a lambda is the worst form of this, especially when suddenly special cases about the item getting, or a new permutation of items, arises exogenously.

Comment: The discussion would be more appropriate for codereview than here, but that's an awful lot of boilerplate to avoid writing `lambda x: x[0].lower(), x[2], x[1]`.. and I'm not sure it's any more robust.  Heck, you've hardcoded the argument which is being lowercased into the very name of the function.. but I suppose YMMV. :-)

Comment: I'm not saying that's the function I would use, it's just quick for this one-off SO question. In my case, `compose` would have already been built long ago and would be part of my Python start-up configs to be always available since it is so important, so it would be heavily amortized. I would write the helper functions as generally as made sense for the application, but in general I would find `lambda x: x[0].lower(), x[2], x[1]` unacceptable long-term.

Comment: To that end, I also include the [Python Infix recipe](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/384122-infix-operators/) as part of my start-up config stuff, and have a number of things, like `compose` (which I use as the infix `|dot|`) ever-present, to cut down on parentheses and nested function calls. On an amortized basis, my code ends up being usually as short or shorter than equivalent lambda passing, with (IMO) much better encapsulation even on the fly.